# HP Quick Test Professional + ASP.NET (possible?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I work for big company on a quite big project in ASP.NET. 
Our supervisors decided that our application need automated tests and they chose 
**HP Quick Test Professional** tool. I have bad feelings about it. Has anyone ever used that tool to test ASP.NET pages? IS it good choice? Do we need any additional tool/addin? Can we use that tool without implementing MVP (or MVC) pattern? I know there are NUnit,XUnit etc. but most of them are prohibited in our company (don't ask why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A larger question would be what you are hoping to obtain from the testing.  HP Quicktest Pro is usually used to automate regression or UI input testing, while NUnit, XUnit, and the like are used to create more focused unit tests, usually revolving around functionality.

Since you are referring to testing ASP.NET pages, I presume you are thinking of automating regression and/or UI testing.  In this case, you don't need to implement MVP/MVC, but it helps.  HP Quicktest is well designed for this setup and you can use the UI to set up tests quickly.  On the other hand, you do not explicitly need it like that.  You may use the Expert View and use VBScript to generally do whatever you please from a testing standpoint.

As for whether or not it's a good choice, that very much depends on your company's situation. At the end of the day, nothing can replace a properly executed regression script done by a warm-blooded human, and if management or the executives at your company don't fully understand that you may get into a situation where they will attempt to replace or subvert human QA, which will be a disaster for everyone involved (voice of experience).  If the higher ups understand the limitations of the software, it can be pretty helpful.  I would not expect it to change your life for the better, but it can be useful to prevent bugs from ever making it out of the dev environment, which can happen a lot if your shop is heavy with junior programmers.

Comment: So it looks that HP Quick Test is different type of testing tool than NUnit or XUnit and doesn't allow us to do unit tests. Anyway, it won't be easy to make unit tests without MVP pattern. Thanks for describing what is the main HP Quick Test purpose and what should we expect from it.

Comment: I think Quicktest will allow you to do unit testing, it's just not the focus.  If unit testing is your goal, though, I have no idea why you'd invest in a commercial solution when there are so many free frameworks out there.  There's even one that comes with the .NET framework itself (see it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147.aspx)), though I don't prefer it.